# connecting controller with model to display results in view page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

So i have this aps.net mvc project in which i created a service layer, model views, controller, and a view page. But i am having trouble displaying my results to the view page. I am starting this would by passing in a specific linq statement in the service layer so i should be able to return it to show up on the view. Here is what i have:

**Service:**

```
public IEnumerable<RoleUser> GetUsers(int sectionID)
    {
        var _role = DataConnection.GetRole<RoleUser>(9, r => new RoleUser
        {
            Name = RoleColumnMap.Name(r),
            Email = RoleColumnMap.Email(r)
        }, resultsPerPage: 20, pageNumber: 1);
        return _role;
    }
```

**Models:**

```
public partial class Role
{
    public RoleView()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<RoleUser>();
    }
    public ICollection<RoleUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class RoleUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult RoleUser(RoleView rvw)
    {
        var rosterUser = new RosterService().GetUsers();
        ViewBag.RosterUsers = rosterUser;
        return View();
    }
```

**View:**

```
<div>
<span>@Model.Name</span>
</div>
```

I am not sure what i am missing or doing wrong but any tips will be great. I basically want to return the results from the linq statement i am testing to see that the connection is correct and functionality is there before enhancing. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I were to go off the code you've provided I would say that I'm unsure how this compiles:

```
public partial class Role
{
    public RoleView()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<RoleUser>();
    }
    public ICollection<RoleUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

it feels like that should be:

```
public partial class RoleView
```

and then I would say that at the top of your view you're missing this:

```
@model NamespaceToClass.RoleView
```

and then I would say you're not going to be able to issue this:

```
@Model.Name
```

because `RoleUser` isn't your model. You're going to need to loop through the users:

```
@foreach (RoleUser ru in Model.Users)
```

and then inside that loop you can build some HTML with this:

```
ru.Name
```

but I would also question your controller. Right now it's receiving a model to return that model. There is some code missing here but generally speaking, inside the method:

```
public ActionResult RoleUser(RoleView rvw)
```

you would actually go get the data, construct the model, and then return that:

```
var users = serviceLayer.GetUsers(...);

// now construct the RoleView model
var model = ...

return View(model);
```

---

Based off of our conversation you currently have something like this in your controller:

```
public ActionResult View(int id) 
{ 
    // get the menu from the cache, by Id 
    ViewBag.SideBarMenu = SideMenuManager.GetRootMenu(id); 
    return View(); 
} 

public ActionResult RoleUser(RoleView rvw) 
{ 
    var rosterUser = new RosterService().GetUsers(); 
    ViewBag.RosterUsers = rosterUser; 
    return View(); 
}
```

but that really needs to look like this:

```
public ActionResult View(int id) 
{ 
    // get the menu from the cache, by Id 
    ViewBag.SideBarMenu = SideMenuManager.GetRootMenu(id); 

    var rosterUser = new RosterService().GetUsers(); 
    ViewBag.RosterUsers = rosterUser; 

    return View(); 
}
```

because you're launching this page from the sidebar which is hitting this action because you're passing the id in the URL. ***You don't even need the other action.***

Comment: Thanks for this great answer i am working through it but quick question. `GetUsers(...)` will that be a method that i have to create in the Model?

Comment: @Amina, nope, that's the method that already exists in the service layer - `public IEnumerable<RoleUser> GetUsers(int sectionID)` - I just didn't fill in the parameter values.

Comment: I see. so when i build - `var users = serviceLayer.GetUsers(...)` gives me this error: an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, property (serviceLayer.GetUsers())

Comment: @Amina, a lot of that was psuedo-code. You're going to have to get to your service layer however you do. Maybe it's not an object - maybe you have a proxy you need to create. It's just leading you down the right path.

Comment: Ok - so i updated my controller method and i have this feeling that something is missing but don't know what

Comment: @Amina, so when you call the service layer `rosterUser` is `null` or has zero items?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27098/discussion-between-michael-perrenoud-and-amina)

Comment: Another side question - i am trying another way to connect and display data and i am trying out with an api controller - would you still be the write person to refer back to?

Comment: @Amina, get some code going and then when you've gotten to a point where it's breaking specifically just ask a different question.